# Implement Bit rate meter in Android

Tags: android, meter

I want to create a bit rate calculator, not in edit text, but use meter for this. My concern is how I orient the meter and get the value of meter, like if we set orient bit rate at 30 MBPS, then my label updated as 30 and when I orient it into 100 MBPS then label update accordingly. Please help me for the same that how I orient meter in android.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want use meter type ui and set its value .

Comment: How do you plan to create your meter? If you mean to create a analog meter and set its current value to a label, then first up, you should implement the meter as such and only then care about the reading to be displayed in a label.